# how to show a pop up on top of a view in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, popup

will like to know if there is any tutorial to teach me how to create a popup view in iphone.

i need to create a tableview, on tap on the cell, it will pop up a view with more information

which looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call you're looking for is:

```
[myTableController.view addSubview:popupView];
```

Create the popupView and load it first, of course!

Answer (score 2):

It is a custom UIView laid over the original view.

use core animation and write one?

```
- (void)animate{

[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0

                            animations:^{ 
                              //animations here
                         }

                           completion:^(BOOL  completed){
                              //cleanup here
                        }
 ];
```

Comment: do u know how the animation behind it ?